# Game related Bluescreens/Crashes

Tags: discussion

Since gaming hardware questions are allowed I wanted to know if it's appropriate to ask a question about Bluescreens and/or crashes that are caused by a Game on gaming.SE. Or should a question like this be asked on another SE site or even another place in general?

Comment: Tl;dr for the dupe: yes, it's on topic. Be *extremely* specific. There's still a very good chance you won't get a good answer because it's not a subject with which we're particularly good.